# Http Get Request GetResponse Error

Tags: c#, get, request, windows-store, webresponse

Im trying to send a get request and get the content of a webpage. i have these code.

```
string url = "www.google.com";

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)response.GetResponse();
```

I found these codes from many site and it is correct but "GetResponse" is giving error. Its explanation below.

Is it a problem of Visual Studio 2012 ? It cant find GetResponse method and just find `GetResponseStream` method when I press G.

I tried to do this with WebClient class but WebClient cannot be found also.
 Do these problems occur because of Visual Studio 2012? or any reason ?

Error   1   'System.Net.HttpWebResponse' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\abidinberkay1\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\App1\App1\BlankPage1.xaml.cs   45  66  App1

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling "response.GetResponse()."  It's **request**.GetResponse().

**Update**: Based on your comments, I'll propose some new code:

```
private async void btnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Note: async added
{
    string url = "www.google.com";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync(); // (note: await added, method call changed to GetResponseAsync()

}
```

I've updated your code to use the C# 5.0 async and await pattern.  This allows you to easily use asynchronous methods while writing code that feels synchronous.  In order to do this, I've added the **async** keyword to the method declaration, prior to the return type (void in this case), and I've added the **await** keyword prior to calling [WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync.aspx).

To answer your question regarding how to know which library you're using: in this case, you chose a Windows Store app.  You should specifically call out what kind of project you're working on - it'll help us nail these kinds of things down faster.

Comment: thank you for prompt reply but still doesn't work. There is no such class GetResponse for request. When I pressed G again just beginGetResponse, endGetResponse, GetResponseAsync exist.

Comment: There is in fact such a method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx .  However, if you're using a different base class library, you'll have to say so.  Are you using Silverlight, perchance, since you are using XAML?

Comment: Is there any way of learning which library I am using ? I installed Visual Studio 2012 but did not look libraries detaily. I am trying to make a program for Microsoft Store Application, I chose "Microsoft Store Application - Blank Project" but I think there is a problem about the library as you said. Should I use silverlight ?

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to do the same but I'm trying to retrieve a xml data to use in my universal app (XAML). How can I store the content of this response in xml format?